# How to get JSON value from JDBC template

Tags: json, spring, spring-jdbc

I have a DB Table `order` where columns are

```
{
  order_id Long PRI,
  order_cost Long,
  String address,
  item_names json
}
```

`item_names` contains `List<String>`

`item_names` will be like: `["Books", "Pens", "papers", "Pencils", "Erasers"]`

I want to get value of `item_names` using `JdbcTemplate`.

For `order_cost` I call `jdbc_template.queryForObject(query_str, Long.class);`
where `query_str` is `"SELECT order_cost FROM order WHERE order_id = " + ordrId;`

But how do I get `item_names` which is of type `json`?

Comment: As far as I know, you need to get `JSON` datatype columns into `String` and then convert that string to JSON object using any library. Reason for this is that JAVA does not have any specific data type for `JSON` hence you need to capture it in `String` and then do conversion.

Comment: What kind of DB are you using? What is `PRI`, and what is the type `address`?

Comment: It is applicable for MySQL and Oracle DB. PRI stands for Primary key. This table is just a place holder. My issue is how to read json value which is in my case List<String>

Comment: Is it OK to read it in String.class and then convert it back? But it should be a list.

Comment: @Ranajit, yes you will need to convert it `String` as JAVA does not have `JSON` datatype, that's what I commented earlier. Then convert that string to required datatype.

Comment: Thanks. I have done it and working fine.